# Android call function once after text has changed inside fragment

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am trying to call a function after a certain period of time after text has changed. I have the delay set up, but my function is getting called twice for some reason. Here is my code:

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {


private EditText mText;
private Handler mHandler;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mHandler = new Handler();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start_process, container, false);     

    mText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    mText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {

            // HERE IS WHERE I WILL CALL MY FUNCTION (Prints show my issue)    

            System.out.println("TEXT CHANGE" + s);              

            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Editable x = s;
                    System.out.println("DELAY TEXT " + xEditable);                      
                }
            };              
            mHandler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
        }
    });        

    return rootView;
}
```

My System.out.println statements look like this:

Text Change H

Text Change Hi

Delay Text Hi

Delay Text Hi

So it looks like when I put my function into runnable, it will run twice. I only want it to run once (Delay Text should only be displayed once). Any ideas what I am doing wrong? My whole goal is to wait a certain time after text has changed (to ensure the text is fully uploaded) and then run my function one time. I have read that AsyncTask could be used, but I am not familiar with that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Runnable is executing twice because afterTextChanged() is getting called after each typed character.

If you want to execute some code after 1 second after the user has started typing you could add a flag to the runnable to make it run just once.

```
 private boolean mFlag = true;


 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {

    // HERE IS WHERE I WILL CALL MY FUNCTION (Prints show my issue)    

    Log.w(TAG, "TEXT CHANGE " + s);

    final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            final Editable x = s;
            Log.w(TAG, "DELAY TEXT " + x.toString());
        }
    }

    if(mFlag){
        mHandler.postDelayed(r, 1000);    
        mFlag = false;
    }

}
```